# How to paste multiple expression using PasteButton?

Tags: notebooks, button, boxes

Is there a way to paste multiple expressions into notebook using `PasteButton`?
For example, I want to do

```
PasteButton["Inputs", {Defer@(a=1;), Defer@(b=2;)}]
```

I want the expressions to be shown in multiple lines just as if we are typing them in, not as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with `PasteButton`, here's ordinary one:

```
Button["Inputs", NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
                 Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{MakeBoxes[a = 1;], "\n", MakeBoxes[b = 1;]}]], 
                      "Input"]]]
```

Here is something more general:

```
Button["Inputs", NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[
       MakeBoxes[a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; e = 1;] /. ";" -> Sequence[";", "\n"]], 
       "Input"]]]
```

Comment: Why not `"\n"` instead of `"\[NewLine]"`?

Comment: @Öskå I don't know ;P probably old habit. Good point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach based on Kuba's approach which allows you to use things like ExpressionCell and Defer.

```
Button["Inputs",
 NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
   {
   ToBoxes@
    ExpressionCell[Defer[a = 1;], "Input", StripOnInput -> True],
   ToBoxes@ExpressionCell[Defer[b = 3;], "Input", StripOnInput -> True]
   }]]
```